# How to configure MongoDB to be able to connect using username and password?

Tags: mongodb

I've a VMWare VM with Ubuntu 16.04.5 and just installed MongoDb 3.6 (not the latest, but it matches production environment)

Inside remote shell, I can run `mongo` and so my `mongod` service is working.

This is parts of `/etc/mongod.conf` file about auth

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.50

security:
  suthorization: enabled
```

I created this user into the db `admin`

```
> use admin

switched to db admin

> show users

{
        "_id" : "admin.realtebo",
        "user" : "realtebo",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
```

Then I restarted `mongod` service.

### The problem

I cannot no more access using `mongo` shell client, it refuses my connection

```
mongo -u realtebo -p passsword_i_setup_for_user_realtebo

MongoDB shell version v3.6.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

2019-01-16T09:06:51.416+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] 
  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, 
  in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused

2019-01-16T09:06:51.416+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] 
  Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, 
  connection attempt failed :
    connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
    @(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

### Important notes

- Sure, removing `authorization: true` and restarting, I can access again, so the daeom in running well, but I'd like to learn the right way: using user and password is the minimum
- I verified that *this exact user/password combo* is working developing a little nodejs app that works using these credentials, and fails without using them, so password *is right*
- I tried to remove auth and verified that "Studio 3T" (a mongodb client) on Windows host can succesfully access MongoDb on the guest, so there are no port/firewalls/other problems with the VM

### Othe tries

Failed specifying the auth db, `admin` as you can see some lines above here.

```
mongo -u realtebo -p passsword_i_setup_for_user_realtebo --authenticationDatabase admin
```

### Simple questions, *I hope*

**What's the right way to create something like a superuser with user and password in mongodb? And then which 'method' must I use from win client and from linux shell client to access it?**

> I know that I then must create another user, a readWrite I suppose, for a single and specific db, but this is not the actual question. For now I need to be able to login as a super user to manage it

Comment: Not an answer, but 2 remarks here:
the property `suthorization: enabled` should be `authorization: enabled`. I have the same config as you, an admin user. It's mandatory to add `--authenticationDatabase admin` when connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an authentication problem, actually the server does not start at all ("Connection refused") because of an error in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file, should be:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Also it's mandatory to add the option `--authenticationDatabase admin` when starting a client.

Comment: you fixed my problem, sorry for waste of time

Answer (score 1):

It was a so simple stupid error.

1. I fixed the following typo, note the `s` instead of `a` in `suthorization`

   ```
   security:
     suthorization: enabled
   ```
2. Restarted service
3. From linux shell I can succesfully connect using

   ```
   mongo -u realtebo -p passsword_i_setup_for_user_realtebo --authenticationDatabase admin
   ```
4. From windows client I setup auth method on `legacy` and entered username and password

Now all works